# Why do we use ring shaped anode in photoelectric effect?

Tags: experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect, applied-physics

We used a ring shaped anode and photons produced by Mercury arc lamp directed toward the anode and strike on cathode surface. But why did not we just let the photons directly strike to the cathode?
Thanks in advance